# Can Crane Style be used while in wild shape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, monk, wild-shape, fighting-style

I got asked this question recently, and RAW nothing seems to be in conflict. Although I have some doubts about the other feats in the chain ([Crane Wing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-wing-combat) & [Crane Riposte](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-riposte-combat/)). So, can [Crane Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/crane-style-combat-style) be used while in [Wild Shape](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes

A druid retains his feats while in wild shape; nothing about style feats in general, or about Crane Style specifically, changes this.

In fact, Crane Wing and Crane Riposte can be used too—but the “free hand” requirement is a bit of a difficulty. If you wild shape into a form that has hands—a primate, usually—then you should be able to use these feats. Otherwise, probably not, though personally I find no reason players in my games shouldn’t be able to hold a claw or similar in reserve (i.e. not use it when attacking) in order to benefit from those feats.

Of course, I would also warn players in my games that all three of these feats are quite poor, and recommend they reconsider taking them at all.